# accessing the property of a data type

Tags: haskell

Here is my code:

```
data Person = Person {name :: String}

greet :: Person -> String -> String
greet person lastName = 
  "Hi my name is " ++ name ++ ", last name: " ++ lastName
```

This is my interpretation of what I've written here: There is a data type `Person` for which there exists a method `name` that returns a string.

There also exists a function `greet` which takes in a `Person` and a `String` and returns a different `String`. However, the greet method calls the `name` method of the `Person` data type to concatenate this string.

However when I compile this code, I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Person -> String'
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `name` is a function you get for free from Record syntax. You can see it's type in `ghci`:

```
λ> :t name
name :: Person -> String
```

You are getting an error because you are trying to apply `++` function to a function named `name` instead of a `String`. So your code should be like this:

```
greet :: Person -> String -> String
greet person lastName = "Hi my name is " ++ name person ++ ", last name: " ++ lastName
```

Answer (score 4):

@Sibi's answer is correct, but with [`RecordWildCards`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards) you can get close to your original:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

data Person = Person {name :: String}

greet :: Person -> String -> String
greet Person{..} lastName = 
    "Hi my name is " ++ name ++ ", last name: " ++ lastName
```

Comment: What is RecordWildCards?

Comment: @dopatraman It is what is known as a language extension. These are pieces of syntax or behavior in addition to the Haskell language specification. They are compiler specific, but GHC supports a fair number. Some of these assist in writing bindings to C libraries, some for more advanced type system features, and some for expanding syntax, such as the one above. For example, to allow for string literals to also act as `Text` or `ByteString`, you can use the `OverloadedStrings` extension. There are a lot of them out there that are fun and useful, but you'll come across them as you learn Haskell.